# Can't set background color because of HTML Hex code

Tags: wpf

I am trying to set the background of a template by using color I found online in HEX code:

```
<Color x:Key="BaseColor">#408DD2</Color>

....

<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
     <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
          <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" 
                Value="{StaticResource BaseColor}" />
     </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

The error I get is:

```
'#FF408DD2' is not a valid value for property 'Background'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Border.Background`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.background%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is of type [`System.Windows.Media.Brush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you cannot assign a [`System.Windows.Media.Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to that.

Instead, create a resource of type `Brush`:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BaseColor" Color="#408DD2"/>
```

or,

have your `Setter` create the Brush to be assigned to that property:

```
 <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background">
     <Setter.Value>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BaseColor}"/>
     </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
```

Answer (score 2):

To set the HEX value of color, use `Brush`, like this:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BaseColor">#408DD2</SolidColorBrush>
```

Answer (score 2):

Background is of type `Brush` and not `Color`. So you need to provide Brush to it:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BaseColor" Color="#408DD2"/>
```